# How to resolve the below es-lint warnings-Warning as ''Expected to return a value"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have the below code which is working fine

```
this.state.fieldsData.advancedSearchComponentData.map((advancedCompDataElement) => {
            if (advancedCompDataElement.isRangeAttribute) {
                advancedCompDataElement.rangeAttributes.map((rangeDataElement) => {
                    if (rangeDataElement.data.value) {
                        searchElement[rangeDataElement.data.searchAttribute] = rangeDataElement.data.value;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (advancedCompDataElement.value)
                  searchElement[advancedCompDataElement.searchAttribute] = advancedCompDataElement.value;
            }
        });
```

but i can see some eslint warnings like

```
Line 138:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
Line 140:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
```

Can some one explain me why i'm getting those errors and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `.map` is to take an array and a callback, and transform each element in the array based on the callback, so as to return a new array with the transformed elements, such as `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `[2, 4, 6, 8]` with `.map(n => n * 2)`. If you use `.map` but don't return anything, that means you aren't using it for its intended purpose - you probably just want to use plain iteration instead, which can be done with `forEach`:

```
this.state.fieldsData.advancedSearchComponentData.forEach((advancedCompDataElement) => {
  if (advancedCompDataElement.isRangeAttribute) {
    advancedCompDataElement.rangeAttributes.forEach((rangeDataElement) => {
```

As the [rule description](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) says:

> Array has several methods for filtering, mapping, and folding. If we forget to write return statement in a callback of those, it’s probably a mistake. If you don’t want to use a return or don’t need the returned results, consider using .forEach instead.